# Node.js winston logging using mail transport to send only uncaughtException as an email

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, winston

Is there any way to send `uncaughtException` to an email address using `Winston` module's `Mail` transport? I don't want to use any other approach to email `uncaughtExceptions`. I kow that there are ways round this but, I am more keen to getting Winston's Mail transport working.

Apparently the configuration does not support

```
handleException: true
```

Would be cool though if it could. I use other transports to log all exceptions but, when it comes to `uncaughtException` exception I not only want to log it but also email myself when they are thrown so I can ssh into the system and resolve the issue. Obviously I will be using either `forever` or `pm2` as supervisor which would restart the app anyway.

There seem to be an open issue about being able to email only exceptions but, nobody has responded to that. I did `+1` the issue in the hope of getting something.

Has anyone used Winston's Mail transport to send `uncaughtException` only. If yes, how did you get around this issue? Sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely enough, I got it to work by changing how I configured the logger. I added the Mail transport inside the `exceptionHandlers` and omitted the `handleException: true` bit. The configuration is as follow:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var Mail = require('winston-mail').Mail;

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({
      name: 'vehicle-log',
      filename: './log/vehicle.log',
      level: 'info',
      timestamp: true,
      colorize: true,
      handleExceptions: true,
      humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
      prettyPrint: true,
      json: true,
      maxsize: 5242880
    })
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.Mail({
      to:'toAddress',
      from:'fromAddress',
      subject: 'uncaughtException Report',
      host:'smtp.relaxitsjustanexample.com',
      username:'emailadd',
      password:'password',
      ssl: true
    })
  ]
});
```

For testing purpose, I through an uncaughtException and made sure that Express don't catch it as follow:

```
router.get('/api/burn', function(req, res) {
    logger.info('ROUTE GET /api/burn');

    process.nextTick(function() {
      throw new Error('Catch me if you can.');
    });
});
```

`uncaughtException` gets logged by File transport as well as emailed by Mail transport.

When it was not working, I had configured the transport differently then I found out that I can use `exceptionHandlers`. I don't know if using `exceptionHanlders` made it work or something else but, regardless it is working.

Comment: ffd don't use gmail in examples, that's like sending a person to casino to earn for a living